# sap.m.FlexBox and OverlayContainer

Tags: sapui5

I'm working on a signature pad feature to my app using [szimek/signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad). When a user presses "add signature" button, the [overlay container](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/ux3/demokit/OverlayContainer.html) pops up. This container is used to sign and accept/clear the signature.

The problem is that I want to align control buttons in a specific way using sap.m.FlexBox, but when I add my FlexBox object to the content of the overlay object, the FlexBox object is not rendered (but the `myhtml` part of the `oOverlayContainer`'s content is rendered and works fine).

Here is the code of the relevant function: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/qirekalija/1/edit?js).

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlexBox control doesn't have `content` aggregation, but `items`:

```
var oButtonContainer = new sap.m.FlexBox({
    justifyContent: sap.m.FlexJustifyContent.SpaceAround,
    alignItems: sap.m.FlexAlignItems.Center,
    items: [oCloseButton, oSubmitSignatureButton, oClearButton],
    fitContainer: true,
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsbin.com/rafawoqove/1/edit?html,output)